# Titanium Studio Cannot create new project

Tags: java, android, titanium, titanium-mobile

I have installed titanium studio 3.0.2.2 in Windows 7 32bit environment and configured Android 4.2.Then created an account with titanium and its working properly when opening the Titanium IDE.But when i try to create a new project it displays an error message like this

```
   [ERROR] Missing required option "--username"
```

Iam using my office LAN.Please help me to solve this problem.

Comment: @title: In my case there was no sdk configured, and the titanium sdk was not updated, doing both solved the problem for me, hope this helps someone who comes here through google

Answer (score 2):

This is not a critical issues.

Currently Latest Titanium Studio version is 3.1.1.GA

You Can try this Go To

Help-->Check for Titanium Updates and Update you SDK.

after this Restrat your PC.
Try again to Build your Project...

Comment: Previously i have installed the latest version.it also produce this error.So i have installed this old version.but still no change.is something wrong with proxy settings? IDE displays me as "welcome back sanjeewa"?.but when try to create a new projects it displays above error message.

Comment: Please, check Internet Connection is available in Your PC. ... ?